"How to find the order of 20 mod 20801"
I did try the order test which gave me an answer $60$, but the actual answer is $15$.
I also tried the Chinese remainder theorem but by letting $x=20^n$ and got an answer $1$, which was obvious but I do not really know how to solve this, since $20$ is not a prime applying order test also becomes a problem

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

A shorter title would be: "How to find the order of $20\mod 20801$".

$20$ has order $5,15,5$ mod $11,31,61$ so has order ${\rm lcm}(5,15,5)=15,$ mod $,{\rm lcm}(11,31,61) = 20801,,$ cf. Remark here. $\ \ $
